# How to use fslint (in particular findnl) on the command line to actually mimic the behavior of the fslint-gui?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, filenames

So I am trying the [`fslint` tools](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/). However, the help included in those tools as well as the `man` page don't indicate that the cleanup actions offered by the `fslint-gui` are also available through `fslint` (CLI) or the individual tools.

I am trying to use `findnl` in particular, and there is no indication of it being able to automatically rename files:

```
$ /usr/share/fslint/fslint/findnl --help
find Name (directory or file) Lint.
Usage: findnl [-1] [-2] [-3] [-p] [[-r] [-f] paths(s) ...]

These options are mutually exclusive (i.e. only the last one takes effect).
-1 is least checking, -3 is most. The default is 2.

-p is most stringent and applies POSIX.1 filename portability testing.
I.E. characters are limited to [A-Za-z0-9_.-] and max name length = 14 and
max path length = 255.

If no path(s) specified then the currrent directory is assumed.
```

It seems to exist for `findup` though (the `-d` for example):

```
$ /usr/share/fslint/fslint/findup --help
find dUPlicate files.
Usage: findup [[[-t [-m|-d]] | [--summary]] [-r] [-f] paths(s) ...]

If no path(s) specified then the currrent directory is assumed.


When -m is specified any found duplicates will be merged (using hardlinks).
When -d is specified any found duplicates will be deleted (leaving just 1).
When -t is specfied, only report what -m or -d would do.

[...]
```

Does anyone know how to use those tools (emphasis on the plural!) on the command line?

I've searched before writing up this question and all I came up with was - depending on the tool - no answer at all (or not better than the vague and brief help) or something tailored to a specific use case that didn't apply and also didn't allow me to generalize the example in any way. I realize that maybe I overlooked it, but then it probably means it's not mentioned prominently enough and this question (and subsequent answers) will help other internauts in the future.